# What is the difference between ViewActions.click() and a custom ViewAction performing only view.performClick()?

Tags: android, android-espresso

The built-in `ViewActions.click()` in Espresso uses a [GeneralClickAction](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/refs/heads/android-support-test/espresso/core/src/main/java/android/support/test/espresso/action/GeneralClickAction.java#69) under the hood to simulate the click event, which does a lot of logic like calculating the coordinates.

My question is how it differs with the following implementation?

```
public class MyClickViewAction {

  public static ViewAction click() {
    return new ViewAction() {
      @Override
      public void perform(UiController uiController, View v) {
          v.performClick();
          uiController.loopMainThreadUntilIdle();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `v.performClick();` would trigger the code flow, your on click listener will be called.
But `ViewActions.click()` will act as if user pressed your view. view will receive onTouch events and then its view job to convert those touch event to a click event and propagate it to your clickListener.

Advantage will be something like if your view have some custom feedback mechanism on user touch, maybe it scales on user touch down and scales back on touch up, you'll be able to test that with Espresso.

Comment: `v.performClick()` will trigger only the click code flow.
`ViewActions.click()` will trigger onTouch of your view which internally might trigger your `onClick` flows